# segmentation fault in string

Tags: c++, c

I am just trying to extract two substrings from a string. But it is showing a segmentation fault.

**The code is:**

```
const char *str;  
char *s1, *s2;

str = "name:d";  
char *pos = strchr(str, ':');
size_t no    = 1,
       index = pos - str;

if (index > 0) 
{
    strncpy(s1, str, index);  
    cout << "name is:" << s1;  
    index++;  
    strncpy(s2, str + index, no);  
    cout << "direction is:" << s2;       
}
```

Comment: Belongs on http://debug-my-code-for-me.com

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. If the latter, use `std::string`.

Comment: @user2114865 pointers are sad if they don't point anywhere

Answer (score 3):

The following two lines are copying into memory referenced by uninitialized pointers:

```
 strncpy(s1,str,index);  
 strncpy(s2,str+index,no);
```

You need to allocate memory for `s1` and `s2` (or just use `std::string` and save yourself the headache).

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated any memory for `s1` or `s2`. What you need to do is use `new` and allocate memory or alternatively use `std::string` and save the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialised `s1` or `s2` to point to anything; so attempting to write to the memory they point to (e.g. `strncpy(s1,str,index)`) gives undefined behavoiur - if you're lucky, a segmentation fault.

If you're writing C, then allocate memory for them; if you're writing C++, use `std::string` to manage memory allocation for you.